# Limit Google Sign-In to .edu accounts in Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor, iron-router, google-signin

I'm trying to limit my Google + Sign-In Button to only allow @something.edu accounts to sign in. How would I go about doing this. This is my code so far:

```
Template.googleLogin.events({
    'click #gLogin': function(event) {
        Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Google login didn't work!");
            }
            else {
                Router.go('/home')
            }


        });
    }
})

Template.primaryLayout.events({
    'click #gLogout': function(event) {
        Meteor.logout(function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Hmm looks like your logout failed. ");
            }
            else {
                Router.go('/')
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `Accounts.config` (in the root directory, so it runs on both the client and server)

```
Accounts.config({ restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'something.edu' })
```

If you need something more custom, you can replace `something.edu` with a method if you need to fine grain your requirement, i.e for any `.edu` domain:

```
Accounts.config({ restrictCreationByEmailDomain: function(address) {
        return new RegExp('\\.edu$', 'i')).test(address)
    }
});
```

Comment: This method didnt work for me. There was no error in log, but somehow it didnt work and user (unwanted) was able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

The accounts package allows configuring account creation domain through:

```
Accounts.config({
  restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'something.edu' 
})
```

But this has some limitations in case of google:

1. This is only client side and only allows for the login form to get properly styled to represent the domain's logo etc. But it can be very easily overcome by crafting the google oauth signin url by hand
2. In case you need to configure extra options like allowing multiple domains or a domain and some outside users (perhaps third party contractors or support from a software company etc) this does not work. In case of accounts-google, the package checks if `restrictCreationByEmailDomain` is a String and if it is instead a function, it just discards it.

Therefore, to be able to properly and securely utilize such functionality, you need to use the official `Accounts.validateNewUser` callback:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function(newUser) {
  var newUserEmail = newUser.services.google.email;
  if (!newUserEmail) throw new Meteor.Error(403,'You need a valid email address to sign up.');
  if (!checkEmailAgainstAllowed(newUserEmail)) throw new Meteor.Error(403,'You need an accepted organization email address to sign up.');
  return true;
});

var checkEmailAgainstAllowed = function(email) {
  var allowedDomains = ['something.edu'];
  var allowedEmails = ['someone@example.com'];
  var domain = email.replace(/.*@/,'').toLowerCase();
  return _.contains(allowedEmails, email) || _.contains(allowedDomains, domain);
};
```

If you want to be extra cautious, you can implement the same for the `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` and `Accounts.onCreateUser` callbacks as well.

Comment: If you run the `Accounts.config` on the server side doesn't it validate it the same way as placing implicit `validateNewUser` rules? : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/58869b050bf5cdc77991505b10c46112d85aff24/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1088-L1112

Comment: Hmm, I've actually been thinking of https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/58869b050bf5cdc77991505b10c46112d85aff24/packages/google/google_client.js#L48 the whole time but never actually looked at the source for `validateNewUser`. Wow! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Had to downvote this, as both claims are false. While it's correct that the client-side script only uses `restrictCreationByEmailDomain()` for styling, proper validation still takes place on the server, whether you return a string or a function. From the client-side script's comments (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-google/google.js#L11): `Note that all this does is change Google's UI --- accounts-base/accounts_server.js still checks server-side that the server has the proper email address after the OAuth conversation.`