# meteor google service-configuration restriction to company emails

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts, google-account

i am building an Meteor App and using these packages for login/accounts:

accounts-base@1.3.6

accounts-password@1.4.2

accounts-google

service-configuration

I set up the service configuration like this:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: "google" },
    { $set: {
        clientId: "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        secret: "xxx"
    } }
);
```

Is it possible to restrict the emails?
If you have a company registered at google and they have their own email adresses like

peter_parker@companyname.com

is it Possible to just allow Login with google with googlemails from @companyname.com?

And if yes, where do i have to configure those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i was looking for in another thread

[Limit Google Sign-In to .edu accounts in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241577/limit-google-sign-in-to-edu-accounts-in-meteor)

_

Nevertheless many thanks